# Warum Drittanbieter?

Tags: meaning, etymology

Wenn ich, häufig günstigere, Ersatzteile, Druckerpatronen oder anderes Verbrauchsmaterial kaufe, dann ist häufig die Rede von Drittherstellern.

Unter dem "Ersthersteller" könnte ich mir ja ja den Originalteilehersteller vorstellen. Aber warum gibt es keinen Zweithersteller?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wenn die [deutsche Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drittanbieter) Recht hat, dann ist der Zweithersteller oder -anbieter ein vom Erstanbieter beauftragter Anbieter. Ich verstehe das in Richtung Lizenzproduktion.

Der korrespondierende [englische Wikipedia-Artikel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-party_source) zählt anders: first party ist der Anbieter (und alles unter dessen Kontrolle), second party der Käufer, und third party sind alle, die weder unter Kontrolle des Anbieters noch Käufers stehen. Der Artikel wirkt auf mich insgesamt überzeugender, und der deutsche gibt ja selbst an, daß der Begriff aus dem Englischen stammt. Am einfachsten fällt es mir, für Software ein Beispiel für "Zweitanbieter" zu konstruieren (vielleicht, weil ich selbst aus der Branche komme): wenn ich zu einem Programm eine bestimmte Erweiterung weder vom Hersteller noch von einem anderen Fremdanbieter beziehen kann und sie mir deswegen entweder selbst programmiere oder auf eigene Rechnung bei jemandem in Auftrag gebe, dann wäre das wohl eine "2nd-party extension".

Answer (score 0):

The second party is the customer involved. In English it's the same, we talk about *third party* components etc.

Comment: +Ingmar I'm definitively NO Zweitanbieter. Second Party might be the proper translation, but its meaning is very different.

Comment: I don't follow. We're talking about "third parties" (or Dritte, in German) all the time; this is no different.  Dritthersteller is a literal translation of third-party manufacturer, i.e. a party that's neither the customer nor the initial vendor. Call them  _Fremdhersteller_ if it makes you feel better.

Comment: My question was not about parties, but about third party vendors. I, as a customer, are no second party vendor.

Comment: I am afraid you are fighting against windmills here. It's not the third vendor, it's any _third-party_-vendor; that's just how it's used.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. It's possible that the second *party* is the customer, but a *customer* is not a *vendor*, which is what is explicitly expressed by *Drittanbieter*.

Comment: The operative term in this case is _Dritt-_, i.e. _third-party_. It's not the third vendor, it's (any) third-party vendor. The German term _Dritthersteller_ or _-anbieter_ might be a bit unsharp in this regard, (_Fremdhersteller_ would be a better term) but that ship has sailed. I for one think this makes a lot of sense, but as always, YMMV.

Comment: @Ingmar: No-one claims it's *the* third vendor rather than any third-party vendor. The issue is that a customer is not a vendor.

Comment: Whatever. I really have nothing to add, so if that explanation still doesn't satisfy you I'm afraid we'll all have to live with that. EOD.